# Generalize an awk program that concatenates csv files and adds a column

Tags: csv, awk

I have these two csv files:

```
$ cat numbers.csv
h1,h2
1, 2
3, 4

$ cat letters.csv
h1,h2
a, b
c, d
```

I want to concatenate both csv files and I want to add a new column with the value `letters` or `columns` if the row comes from `letters.csv` or `numbers.csv` so I wrote this awk command (because I'm trying out awk) that does the job:

```
$ awk 'NR==1 {print new_column","$0} fname != FILENAME { fname = FILENAME; idx++ } FNR > 1 && idx == 1 { print group1","$0 } FNR > 1 && idx == 2 { print group2","$0 }' new_column=type group1=letters group2=numbers letters.csv numbers.csv
```

`new_column` is of the column that is going to be added

`group1` is the is the value of `new_column` if the row is added from the `letters.csv` file

`group2` is the is the value of `new_column` if the row is added from the `numbers.csv` file

The output I get is:

```
type,h1,h2
letters,a, b
letters,c, d
numbers,1, 2
numbers,3, 4
```

The problem is that I don't know if there is a way to make the awk program run with n arguments and n files without having to rewrite it everytime like so:

```
$ awk '....' new_column=group_name group1=letters group2=numbers ... groupN=whatever  letters.csv numbers.csv .... morefiles_to_N.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this

```
% awk 'NR==1{print "type,"$0} 
       FNR==1{nm=FILENAME; sub(/\..*/,"",nm); next} 
             {print nm","$0}' num.csv let.csv
type,h1,h2
num,1, 2
num,3, 4
let,a, b
let,c, d
```

Comment: Clever use of the csv filenames to "store" the grouping values and it would work for any number of files

Answer (score 2):

I suggest taking look at using single variable for ramming all needed names and then deserialize it using [`split` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html), consider simple example, let say I have `file1.txt` with following content

```
1
2
3
```

`file10.txt` with following content

```
10
20
```

and `file100.txt` with following content

```
100
```

and want to fuse them, giving names ABLE, BAKER, CHARLIE for data from respective filess, then I could do

```
awk -v names=ABLE:BAKER:CHARLIE 'BEGIN{split(names,arr,/:/)}FNR==1{i+=1}{print arr[i] "," $0}' file1.txt file10.txt file100.txt
```

gives output

```
ABLE,1
ABLE,2
ABLE,3
BAKER,10
BAKER,20
CHARLIE,100
```

Explanation: I elected `:` for separating names, when making choice keep in mind separator MUST NOT be present in any name. In `BEGIN` I split names at `:` into array `arr`, so `arr[1]` becomes `ABLE`, `arr2` becomes `BAKER`, `arr3` becomes `CHARLIE`. For each first row of file (`FNR`) I increase `i` by 1. For each row I `print` name concatenated with whole line (`$0`) using `,` character.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Comment: This would also work for any number of files but I would have to add the FNR==1 condition to take into account the headers. I didn't know about `split`. Very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v header=type -v groups=letters,numbers '
    BEGIN{ OFS=","; split(groups, grps,",") } 
    FNR==1{i++} 
    NR==1{ print header,$0; next } 
    FNR!=1{ print grps[i],$0 }
' letters.csv numbers.csv

type,h1,h2
letters,a, b
letters,c, d
numbers,1, 2
numbers,3, 4
```

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for `BEGINFILE` or change that to `FNR==1`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding a no awk answer because I know you are looking for a solution using also other tools (as [qsv](https://github.com/jqnatividad/qsv/discussions/1053)).

The tool I use for this kind of task is [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.8.0/installing-miller/). Running

```
mlr --csv put '$type=sub(FILENAME,"\..+","")' letters.csv numbers.csv
```

you get

```
h1,h2,type
a, b,letters
c, d,letters
1, 2,numbers
3, 4,numbers
```

`put` is the verb to build Miller expressions. Here I create the new field `type`, I put it equal to the [`FILENAME`](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.8.0/glossary/#filename) built-in variable. I use the [`sub` function](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.8.0/reference-dsl-builtin-functions/index.html#sub) to remove the file extension.

If you want `type` ad the first field simply add `reorder -f type`

```
mlr --csv put '$type=sub(FILENAME,"\..+","")' then reorder -f type letters.csv numbers.csv
```

Comment: Yes this is the same technique this [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76506519/1128695) uses.
I didn't know about `miller` before so I'll make sure to check it out

Comment: @PerseP I have added it, because Miller is a great product with a great documentation